# How could I merge two dictionaries, summing values of same keys?

Tags: prolog, swi-prolog

What I want is something like `merge(Dict1, Dict2, Merged)` that behaves like the following:

```
?- merge(counter{a: 1, b: 2}, counter{a: 3, c: 4, d: 5}, Merged).
Merged = counter{a: 4, b: 2, c: 4, d: 5}
```

What should I do to achieve this? I'm totally new to logic programming, so I end up failing trying to write something that looks like a terrible port of `for` loop of other languages.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
dicts_merge_add(Dict1, Dict2, DictMerged) :-
    % Convert to sorted key-value pairs
    dict_pairs(Dict1, Tag, Pairs1),
    dict_pairs(Dict2, Tag, Pairs2),
    % Merge the pairs
    pairs_merge_add(Pairs1, Pairs2, PairsMerged),
    % Convert to dict
    dict_pairs(DictMerged, Tag, PairsMerged).


% When reached end of 1 list, insert the remains of the other list
pairs_merge_add([], T, T) :- !.
pairs_merge_add(T, [], T) :- !.

pairs_merge_add([K-V1|T1], [K-V2|T2], L) :-
    % Keys are same
    !,
    Sum is V1 + V2,
    L = [K-Sum|Merg],
    pairs_merge_add(T1, T2, Merg).

pairs_merge_add([K1-V1|T1], [K2-V2|T2], L) :-
    K1 @< K2,
    !,
    L = [K1-V1|Merg],
    pairs_merge_add(T1, [K2-V2|T2], Merg).

pairs_merge_add([K1-V1|T1], [K2-V2|T2], L) :-
    K1 @> K2,
    !,
    L = [K2-V2|Merg],
    pairs_merge_add([K1-V1|T1], T2, Merg).
```

Result in swi-prolog:

```
?- D1 = counter{a: 1, b: 2, z:6},
D2 = counter{a: 3, c: 4, z:8, d: 5},
time(dicts_merge_add(D1, D2, Merg)).
% 17 inferences, 0.000 CPU in 0.000 seconds (88% CPU, 389265 Lips)
D1 = counter{a:1,b:2,z:6},
D2 = counter{a:3,c:4,d:5,z:8},
Merg = counter{a:4,b:2,c:4,d:5,z:14}.
```

Simple performance test:

```
?- C = 30_000, numlist(1, C, L1N),
findall(N-N, member(N, L1N), L1),
dict_pairs(D1, v, L1), numlist(1, C, L2N),
findall(N-N, member(N, L2N), L2), dict_pairs(D2, v, L2),
time(merge(D1, D2, D3)), sleep(10).
% 180,005 inferences, 5.475 CPU in 5.486 seconds (100% CPU, 32877 Lips)

Vs mine: time(dicts_merge_add(D1, D2, D3))
% 60,005 inferences, 0.012 CPU in 0.012 seconds (100% CPU, 4987461 Lips)
```

This shows the huge performance advantage from using the fact that the lists are sorted.

Comment: So you check key equality by variable name. Thanks for the idea and this will help me a lot keep prolog-ing! Much appreciated.

Comment: @wooseop this is terrible code. You really shouldn't need to convert from a dict to a list of pairs and back.

Comment: This code takes advantage of the fact that both lists will be sorted, for performance.

Comment: Added performance comparison :-)

Answer (score 1):

This approach gets the entries from A, recurses over them and merges them into B:

```
merge(A, B, Merged) :-
     dict_pairs(A, _, Pairs),     % Pairs are an ordered set
     merge_(Pairs, B, Merged).


merge_([], Merged, Merged).       % No more pairs, merge finished.

merge_([K-V|Ps], B, Merged) :-    % Merge Key-Value from A.

     (get_dict(K, B, Bval) ->     % Get the matching item from B.
        Sum is V + Bval           % if success, sum their values.
      ; Sum is V),                % if not, just the value from A.

    put_dict(K, B, Sum, B_),      % merge into B.
    merge_(Ps, B_, Merged).       % merge remaining pairs into B.
```

On [SWISH](https://swish.swi-prolog.org/):

```
?- _D1 = counter{a: 1, b: 2, z:6},
   _D2 = counter{a: 3, c: 4, z:8, d: 5},
   time(merge(_D1, _D2, Merg)).

Merg = counter{a:4, b:2, c:4, d:5, z:14}

19 inferences, 0.000 CPU in 0.000 seconds (116% CPU, 827526 Lips)
```